# How do I move one table to another if there is not already a match of one of the fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-table

I am having trouble getting things moved in a database. I have two tables with different column names the one that is the same name is "zip" but they have the same data. I want to move from table A to table b if the zip code doesn't already exist in table b. I am using mysql command line.

Comment: Does this mean you will end up with the same data in two different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `INSERT INTO....SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO TableB(colName)
SELECT colName 
FROM    TableB b
        LEFT JOIN TableA a
            ON a.colName = b.colName
WHERE   a.colName IS NULL
```

`TableA.colName` will be `NULL` if it does not exists on `TableB`. just change `colName` to the columns names in your tables.

**UPDATE 1**

```
INSERT INTO skadate_location_city
    (
        Feature_int_id,
        Admin1_str_code,    
        Country_str_code,
        Feature_dec_lat,    
        Feature_dec_lon,
        zip
    )
SELECT  
        a.city_id     AS Feature_int_id,
        a.state_id    AS Admin1_str_code, 
        a.country_id  AS Country_str_code,
        a.latitude    AS Feature_dec_lat,
        a.longitude   AS Feature_dec_lon,
        a.zip
FROM    skadate_location_zip a
        LEFT JOIN skadate_location_city b
            ON a.zip = b.zip
WHERE   b.zip IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: I think that may only work if the column names are the same. I cant get it to work.

Comment: can you post the query you have created?

Comment: [code]insert into skadate_location_city(Feature_int_id, Admin1_str_code, Country_str_code, Feature_str_name, Feature_dec_lat, Feature_dec_lon, zip)  select Feature_int_id, Admin1_str_code, Country_str_code, Feature_str_name, Feature_dec_lat, Feature_dec_lon, zip from skadate_location_city b left join skadate_location_zip a on a.zip = b.zip where a.zip is null;
[/code]

Comment: what errors do you get? are columns `Feature_int_id, Admin1_str_code, Country_str_code, Feature_str_name, Feature_dec_lat, Feature_dec_lon, zip` from `skadate_location_city` AND `Feature_int_id, Admin1_str_code, Country_str_code, Feature_str_name, Feature_dec_lat, Feature_dec_lon, zip` from `skadate_location_city` ? you said that the have different column names right? could you include the schema of your tables please?

Comment: ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: choose the database first, eg `USE database;`

Comment: yeah sorry the error is ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Feature_int_id' in 'field list'

Comment: we can't move to chat since you haven't enought reputation yet. to answer your question quickly, please provide the schema of your tables  :D

Comment: skadate_location_zip moving from to skadate_location_city

Comment: no, that's not what i want, I want the structures of your table. What are the columns in table `skadate_location_zip` as well as `skadate_location_city`. you need to put their correct column names.

Comment: skadate_location_zip  zip country_id state_id(index) city_id (index unique) latitude longitude // skadate_location_city  Feature_int_id(city_id)  Admin1_str_code(state_id) Country_str_code Feature_str_name (blank) Feature_dec_lat(latitude) Feature_dec_lon longitude zip

Comment: ok i tried it runs for a while and then ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' i deleted the entry with 0 and ran again with the same result.

Comment: what is your primary key on table skadate_location_city?

Comment: ok I got there was a few with 0 that worked great I want to thanks for your help. You saved me alot of time for moving them 1 at a time

Comment: Yo're welcome! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.